# NodeJS How to create asynchronus function and then call it

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to make a function to list the file in some directory, and filtered it by extension:

here is my code look like:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var filterList = function (path, ext) {
    return fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (path.extname(files[i]) === '.' + ext) {
                    return console.log(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

filterList(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

but it returns this error:

```
if (path.extname(files[i]) === '.' + ext) {
                         ^
TypeError: path.extname is not a function
```

Any idea why?

Comment: extname is not a function, its an attribute, try files[i].extname

Comment: path.extname is a function @javaguest See: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p

Comment: yes its a function, if I run the code without define it in a `filterList` function it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change name of arg from `path` to `_path`, its conflicting

```
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path');

var filterList = function (_path, ext) {
  return fs.readdir(_path, function (err, files) {
   if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (path.extname(files[i]) === '.' + ext) {
                return console.log(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
 });
};

filterList(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```